# Printing out a list of values from a column in one table for every row with an overlapping interval in another table

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to compare values in two columns in one table "r" to values in two columns in another table "f", and print the value in a third column from "f" for every row in "r" where "r" values overlap "f" values.

Table r:

```
> rn=c("i","ii","iii","iv","v","vi","vii","viii")
> rs=c(1,21,3,23,6,28,7,26)
> re=c(10,30,17,42,18,43,11,31)
> r=data.frame(rn,rs,re);r

    rn rs re
1    i  1 10
2   ii 21 30
3  iii  3 17
4   iv 23 42
5    v  6 18
6   vi 28 43
7  vii  7 11
8 viii 26 31
```

Table f:

```
> fn=c("a","b")
> fs=c(5,25)
> fe=c(15,40)
> f=data.frame(fn,fs,fe)
> f$fl=f$fe-f$fs;f

  fn fs fe fl
1  a  5 15 10
2  b 25 40 15
```

Ultimately, my desired output would be an additional column in the "r" table that listed the corresponding f$fl value in the "f" table if the r$rs to r$re interval overlaps the f$fs to f$fe interval.

Desired output:

```
     rn rs re flen
1    i  1 10   10
2   ii 21 30   15
3  iii  3 17   10
4   iv 23 42   15
5    v  6 18   10
6   vi 28 43   15
7  vii  7 11   10
8 viii 26 31   15
```

What I've tried:

```
> setDT(r)[f, flen := fl, on = .(re >= fs, re <= fe)][,flen := nafill(flen, 'locf')];r
     rn rs re flen
1:    i  1 10   10
2:   ii 21 30   15
3:  iii  3 17   10
4:   iv 23 42   10
5:    v  6 18   10
6:   vi 28 43   10
7:  vii  7 11   10
8: viii 26 31   15
```

This doesn't quite work

Comment: Can you please specify the logic once more because I am trying to understand the comparison between corresponding columns are correct or not

Comment: flen corresponds to the f$fl column of "f" which is just f$fe-f$fs. So flen values should correspond to the differences between fs and fe. Basically, if an rs:re interval overlaps an fs:fe interval, I want to print the corresponding length of the fs:fe interval at the end of each row in the "r" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can do a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(r)[f, flen := fl, on = .(re >= fs, re <= fe)]
r[f, flen := fl, on = .(rs >= fs, rs <= fe)]
r[f, flen := fl, on = .(rs <= fs, re >= fe)]
```

-output

```
r
#     rn rs re flen
#1:    i  1 10   10
#2:   ii 21 30   15
#3:  iii  3 17   10
#4:   iv 23 42   15
#5:    v  6 18   10
#6:   vi 28 43   15
#7:  vii  7 11   10
#8: viii 26 31   15
```

Comment: I edited my "r" table slightly so that the first 4 intervals do not numerically come before the last 4 intervals, and now your solution doesn't quite work properly. Can you explain what each part of your solution does?

Comment: @Digsby thank you for the reply.  The non equi join is based on the comparison between those corresponding columns.  Do you have other comparison as well

Comment: I think the problem stems from the overlap criteria, and the 'locf' argument. The solution posted, looks like it should carry forward "flen" until the command reaches a new overlap between the two columns from each table, but I want it to report the appropriate "flen" each time a "fs:fe" interval overlaps a "rs:re" interval. The overlap criteria look like they would recognize when "re" ends between "fs" and "fe" but would not account for overlaps where "rs:re" is larger than "fs:fe" or overlaps "rs" falls between "fs:fe" and ends above "fe".

Comment: @Digsby when `rs` `re` is larger than fs, fe, do you want opposite comparison

Comment: @Digsby I have updated the post.  I think you need one more comparison Can you help me with that.  Now only 2 rows are NA ie. 3rd and 4th.  I think it is a different comparison

Comment: No, if `rs``re` is larger than `fs``fe`, I would still like to print the `fl` from `f` as `flen` in `r` for cases when there is any overlap between `rs``re` and `fs``fe`.

Comment: You're close, now I need a comparison where `rs` `re` spans `fs` `fe`; so cases where `rs<=fs` and `re>=fe`.

Comment: @Digsby thank you.  I. updated.  I guess it now works

Comment: Got it! It's r[f, flen := fl, on = .(rs <= fs, re >= fe)]. I finally understood how to use the command.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @akrun. You are awesome!